# How to separate views in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

this is my code:

**routes.rb**

```
get '/admin', :to => "admin#index"
namespace :admin do
  resources :questionnaires, :users, :campaigns
end
```

**admin_controller.rb**

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

**campaigns_controller.rb**

```
module Admin
    class CampaignsController < AdminController
        def index
        end

        def new
        end

        def create
        end

        def show
        end

        def edit
        end

        def update
        end

        def destroy
        end
    end
end
```

questionnaires and users controllers are exactly same of campaigns.

When i try to access to:

```
/admin/campaigns
```

The view is the index view of admin.

folder controller looks like that:

```
controllers
| admin
  | campaigns_controller.b
  | questionnaires_controller.rb
  | users_controllers.rb   
  admin_controller.rb
```

folder views looks like that:

```
views
| index.html.haml
| admin
  | questionnaires
  | | index.html.haml
  | users
  | | index.html.haml
  | index.html.haml
```

How i can separate my views for each resource ?

Comment: What happens when you visit `/admin/questionnaires`?

Comment: The same as `/admin/campaigns`

Comment: @spuyet remove this line and try once `get '/admin', :to => "admin#index"`

Comment: Doesn't works and now my `/admin` is down. I just want separate views of each resource in my folder views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your routes to this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :questionnaires, :users, :campaigns
end
get '/admin', :to => "admin#index" # this line at bottom
```